# Set an ImageIcon using Images contained in ArrayList

Tags: java, user-interface, imageicon

I'm trying to set an imageicon for a button using an arraylist of ImageIcon. I have a default image for the buttons when the gui loads but when I click on one I want to get an image from the array list of Icon Images. Right now when I click it is blank.

```
private ArrayList<ImageIcon> images = new ArrayList<>();
images.add(new ImageIcon("/images/image1.png"));
        images.add(new ImageIcon("/images/image2.png"));
        images.add(new ImageIcon("/images/image3.png"));
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(btnNewButton.getIcon().equals(cardBack)) {
                    btnNewButton.setIcon(images.get(1));
                } else {
                    btnNewButton.setIcon(cardBack);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try putting the entire path to your image file instead of one starting at /images -- the leading slash suggests that the ImageIcon constructor will regard 'images' as a root directory, which may not be what you meant. If it doesn't work if you use "C:/users/you/projects/testImage/images/image1.png" or whatever, then you know you have a different problem. Remember that backslash, should you use that, is the escape character in strings and has to be doubled to show up once.

Comment: @arcy I know there are images there because I tested setting the image icon with SetIcon(new IconImage(main.get....) and it worked so I know there are images in the array list. I just cant get them to show up for some reason.

Comment: Is this done on the UI thread? Do you repaint after you change the UI? I'm just shooting in the dark here, I don't have enough information to inform my guesses any further than that.